# Purpose of solr boost function

Tags: java, boost, solr, lucene

I came across a set of legacy code in which some dynamic variables are set to solr boost function.

```
String query = "{!boost b=sum(" + searchQuery.getFieldsToBoost() + ")}";
```

This breaks in case `searchQuery.getFieldsToBoost()` contains any of these punctuations `+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \`

So I tried to escape these special chars in boost sum() function , using the approach given in https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html

But the above approach didn't work.
Following is the error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Expected ',' at position 631 in 'sum(itemAttributes_A3,itemAttributes_ASD,itemAttributes_ASD1,itemAttributes_Bang,itemAttributes_Color,itemAttributes_ES,itemAttributes_El_Segundo_only,itemAttributes_Environment_Friendly,itemAttributes_MossPoint_only,itemAttributes_NAUFIL,itemAttributes_NorthDakota_only,itemAttributes_Off_Contract,itemAttributes_On_Contract,itemAttributes_PBINFO,itemAttributes_PPD,itemAttributes_Palmdale_only,itemAttributes_Preferred,itemAttributes_Punchout,itemAttributes_RanchoBernardo_only,itemAttributes_SEARCHABLE,itemAttributes_Services,itemAttributes_SpacePark_only,itemAttributes_custom_flag12,itemAttributes_FL_01,itemAttributes_hyphen\-field,itemAttributes_icon,itemAttributes_required_PPD,itemAttributes_semicolon;field,itemAttributes_space_field,attributes_Green_certified,attributes_Preferred_contract,attributes_Service_Disabled_Veteran,attributes_Veteran_Owned,attributes_Minority_Owned,attributes_Woman_Owned,attributes_Hubzone,attributes_Tier_II_Contract,attributes_Red_Attribute)'
```

So I thought of replacing all special chars in `searchQuery.getFieldsToBoost()` to underscore.

But I don't know how it will effect the search results / boost results.

Basically it would be very nice if someone can help me with escaping the special chars or can give me an overview of repercussions after replacing special characters to underscore.

I am failing to understand what is the purpose of boost in solr.

Comment: could you show what getFieldsToBoost returns?

Comment: it returns comma seperated string in format itemAttributes_{Dynamic_FieldName}
When this {Dynamic_FieldName} contains any above specified special char, then it breaks.

Comment: if you do not get what is boosting, why you are using it?

Comment: Does boost function tends to change the search result also?
Can you please explain why it is basically used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the boosting function is to boost specific terms or documents or fields, when returning results. It will not add or change result set, e.g. it could only change the order.

So, for example if you decided that field **title**, is more important than **description**, you could set it with boosting. Same could be done, if you decided, that term **Nike** is more important than term **Adidas**.

Some additional information [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_1/scoring.html#Score%20Boosting)